# Print function name private method of IIFE

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor sever code has `printFuncName` as a private method to a IIFE. When it is called from a public method, it gives the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Why is it doing this and How can it be fixed so that it prints the function name where is is called from? Thanks

```js
funcObj = (function() {

  const printFuncName = (str) => {
    const info = str ? ' ' + str + ' ' : ' ';
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller.name + info); //<---- Error line
  };

  return {
    myPub: () => {
      printFunctionName('info');
    }

  }

}());
```

Comment: There is no standard way to reference the caller.

Comment: @Oriol And what is the alternate solution?

Comment: There is no solution. Why do you need the caller?

Comment: @Oriol All what I am after is to have a method so that it prints out the name of the calling function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to access the caller of `printFuncName`, the problem is that it's an arrow function, and therefore has no `arguments` binding. You are accessing the `arguments` of the IIFE.

Anyways, you should never use `arguments.callee`. It's not standard and you can just reference the function:

```js
(function() {
  const printFuncName = (str) => {
    const info = str ? ' ' + str + ' ' : ' ';
    console.log(printFuncName.caller.name + info); // "myPub info " (maybe)
  };
  return {
    myPub() {
      printFuncName('info');
    }
  }
}()).myPub();
```

Be aware `caller` is also not standard. You should not use this. Do not rely on it. It will throw in strict mode. May not work in sloppy mode.

Answer (score 2):

*Warning: what follows is a hack. The kosher way of doing this is passing the name as an arugment to the function. It's better than the `arguments.callee` approach, though, so use it if you must.*

If you create an `Error` object, you can inspect the `stack` to get the chain of function names:

```
new Error().stack.split('\n')
[ 'Error',
  '    at repl:1:1',
  '    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:22:35)',
  '    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:96:12)',
  '    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:21:12)',
...]
```

Your caller's name will be in that list, along with file and line/col information. Note that many JS functions are **not named**, so this is limited.